# Which Cmake variables should one know the meaning of?

Tags: variables, cmake

I am new to CMake. There are so many CMake variables available and I am interested in which of them do you use the most. Or which of them do you even know by heart? Which of them should I use?

Answer (score 2):

You can find a great summary [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/Useful-Variables) and the full list of the variables used in the [`CMake 3.12`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/manual/cmake-variables.7.html).

- `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`: You can always reference to the current directory with this variable.
- `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`: You can set what is the purpose of the build. Usually Release or Debug for testing.
- `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`: You can set custom parameters passed to c++ compiler. It is recommended to append to the default values.
- `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID` or `CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME`: Sometimes your need to know what is the current compiler in case of cross-platform application. Think about `pthread`.
- `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`: In case of cross compiling you have to set your compiler
- `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`: You can specify which c++ standard is used. In case of `gcc` `--std` flag will be set.

Note: For most of the variables for `c++` (`CMAKE_CXX_*`) there exists a `c` variant (`CMAKE_C_`).

Comment: It's only an opinion, I use CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE, CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR and CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS the most. By the way I'm not shouting, this is a naming convention in cmake.